# Access swagger-ui docker instance from nginx sub-location

Tags: nginx, swagger-ui

I'm having trouble getting the Docker container to serve the static assets for swagger-ui behind my nginx proxy. My nginx config is:

```
server {
    server_name api.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    location ^~ /docs {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9505/;
    }
    location / { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9005; }
}
```

Where our main API responds at the root location, and proxies to the swagger docker container if /docs is specified in the url, launched via:

```
docker run -d -p 9505:8080 --name swagger -e API_URL=https://api.example.com/swagger.json swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

I get the swagger-ui index.html contents when hitting `https://api.example.com/docs` but all the static assets 404 because they are trying to call `https://api.example.com/swagger-ui.css`, for example.

I'd prefer not to put a `try_files` in my root location block because then I end up with a lot of extra processing forcing all normal API requests though the swagger proxy first before erroring and going into the proper API proxy.

Is there some easy config change I'm missing about getting swagger to run at a sub-location like this?

Comment: Looks like changing my location to: `location ^~ /docs/`, with the trailing slash has fixed the problem? I'm not entirely sure why I'll have to get into the nginx docs further

Comment: I know this is old but I've found that both the location and the proxied path require the trailing slash, doesn't work without them both.